# Positive rational raised to positive irrational is always irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I've been puzzling over this question about number theory.

Ignoring complex numbers,
and working only with positive numbers:

Can one say that a positive rational number raised to a positive irrational exponent is always irrational?

Thank you,
Hein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example $x:=\log_2(3)$ is irrational but $2^x=3$.

Comment: Thanks so much, much appreciated

Comment: And the reason it's irrational: if we had $\log_2 3 = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p, q$ positive integers, then we would have $2^p = 3^q$, contradicting the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique factorization into primes).

Comment: Thanks @DanielSchepler